# Why is William Playfair seldom heard about in mathematics?

Tags: statistics

William Playfair was a Scottish engineer and economist, who invented the pie and bar charts as well as the line graph, which have all played an indubitably ubiquitous role in modern statistics.
I hadn't actually come across Playfair, before I browsed Colin Stuart's Maths 100 Numbers book. The book put William Playfair as follows:
"It's fair to say the inventor of the ubiquitous line graph, bar chart and pie chart is not a household name."
What is it that deterred him from being a household name, given the contributions he made to statistics? Even in the scientific community, since statistics plays such a fundamental role in modelling numerous phenomena?

Comment: Bar and pie charts do not really belong to mathematics: these are just visualization tools.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, questions of the form "Why doesn't X get much attention" are unanswerable because they're opinion-based.